# Nautilus "unable to mount <volume>" and "not authorized" and LightDM keeps sending me back to login screen on shutdown and restart

Tags: nautilus, lightdm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't mount filesystems and computer won't shut down](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69082/cant-mount-filesystems-and-computer-wont-shut-down)

Using Nautilus I can't get my internal or external volumes to mount and get "unable to mount " and "not authorized" after an update of Ubuntu 11.10 beta and also I cannot reboot normally instead I need to reboot using terminal as root. Notes that i can mount my volumes using terminal as root.

Rebooting and shutting down just send me back to unity-greeter lightdm login screen.

Answer (score 1):

This was happening to me. It looked like the upgrade removed the partition entry from /etc/fstab. Try putting it back in.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem here. Special thanks to Peds, your answer put me on the right track. My solution hasn't fixed everything but I did get some functionality back by adding the cdrom entry back to fstab.

```
/dev/cdrom  /media/cdrom    auto    ro,noauto,user,exec     0 0
```

and then running the following from terminal:

```
sudo mkdir /media/cdrom
```

Unity doesn't show the correct title on the device after changing disks this way. But mounting works. The fstab entry was missing after update and the folder for the mount point was missing too.

Hope this helps someone in the know come up with a proper fix.