# Can't mount filesystems and computer won't shut down

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, mount, shutdown, lightdm

I've done a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10 and ran the recommended upgrades. Two things are not working properly.

- My windows drives, USB drives, external hard disk cannot be mounted. The below error is given

> Unable to mount the filesystem, Not Authorized.

- The laptop wouldn't shut down or restart. Lightdm login screen is displayed upon giving both the commands.

Comment: Can you split this up into two questions? The system works best when there's one question per post, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem. Here is my solution:

1. login as root. (I had given password for root, "sudo passwd").
2. go to system setting -> user account -> youruser
3. change "Administration" to "Standart" and turn off automatic login.
4. reboot
5. repeat step 1 and 2.
6. change "Standart" to "Administration"
7. login as youruser.

Then, I can mount filesystem easily.

I hope it will work for you too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have no permission to shut down or restart.

Go to your terminal (Ctrl+Alt+t) and run:

```
sudo poweroff
```

Answer (score 0):

Won't shut down? If that was true, I'd definitely buy your laptop from you. But what's more likely is simply that you haven't tried hard enough...

Make sure you don't have any background installs or anything going on. Unplug your laptop. Take out the battery.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used `sudo shutdown -h now`?